# If 0 or "" delete row: code works but very slow

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Question:

With the recorder and help on this forum I made a code (for a button). Column 'i' has got (from row 25) 'Pcs' or a number. My Macro finds Pcs and changes it to "" and than the macro deletes "" and 0's. lenght of the filled cells is variable, so I made 500 as 'end' but it never reaches that. If I run the macro, it works and does the job, but takes very long, especially because it has to do 500 lines..

```
Sub Fix()

Dim intEnd As Integer
Range("M1").Select
Cells.Replace What:="pcs", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
intEnd = 500

Range("I25").Select

Do Until ActiveCell.Row = intEnd

If Int(ActiveCell.Value) = 0 Then
Range(ActiveCell.Row & ":" & ActiveCell.Row).Delete
intEnd = intEnd - 1
Else
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
End If

Loop
End sub
```

I was happy that I could make this macro with help of the forum and the recorder, but now I am stuck speeding it up, no real clue where to start. Does anybody has a tip?

Thanks, if more info or effort needed, please let me know.

Comment: Turn off calculations and screen updating.

Comment: Also rework the code so it does not `.Select` each cell.

Comment: @ScottCraner: thanks, I tried it with [this SO topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) but will review again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub fix3()


Dim intEnd As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

On Error GoTo getout
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change to your sheet
ws.Cells.Replace What:="pcs", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

intEnd = ws.Range("I" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

For i = intEnd To 25
    If Int(ws.Cells(i, "I").Value) = 0 Then
        ws.Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next i
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub

getout:
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Curiosity question about toggling the automatic calculation.  So you turn off automatic calculation...which I kind of like.  You manipulate your arbitrary 1 million cells of data with some code, and at the very end you turn you automic calc back on.  When its turned back on does it automatically do a calculation? or do you need to do something in a cell to trigger an autocalc to occur?

Comment: you know, I do not know the answer to that question.  I would assume it would wait for the next time that calculation is warranted.

Comment: might need to tac on an application.calc or whatever the VBA code is at the end.

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks for your help, your code somehow did not work properly, but I used the Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic.. now it takes 1 second in stead of 60! so this is way better that it was! thanks !

Comment: @bart1701 what did it do wrong?  What error?  I could not test it.

Comment: maybe because any text will error at `If Int(ws.Cells(i, "I").Value) = 0 Then` and the sub will be exited then... (just a guess)

Comment: @DirkReichel I assumed that since it was in the OP that it would not return an error.  But I like yours better.

Answer (score 3):

To do it in a fast use able way, you can use this:

```
Sub DelMe()
  Dim i As Long, x As Variant, y As Range
  With Sheets("Sheet1")
    x = .Range("I1", .Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp)).Value
    If UBound(x) < 25 Then Exit Sub
    For i = 25 To UBound(x)
      If x(i, 1) = 0 Or x(i, 1) = "" Or InStr(1, x(i, 1), "pcs", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        If y Is Nothing Then
          Set y = .Rows(i)
        Else
          Set y = Union(y, .Rows(i))
        End If
      End If
    Next
    y.EntireRow.Delete xlUp
  End With
End Sub
```

It simply deletes all ranges (which you want to be deleted) at once.

If you have any questions, just ask :)

Comment: thanks for your effort, I get a "run-time error 91', "object variable with block variable not set".. y.EntireRow.Delete xlUp is the problem they say?

any advise? not very skilled with array.

Comment: Oh sorry... `Set y = Intersect(y, .Rows(i))` should be `Set y = Union(y, .Rows(i))`... big mistake