# Fastest way to delete rows which cannot be grabbed with SpecialCells

Tags: vba, excel

Based [on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36867552/if-0-or-delete-row-code-works-but-very-slow) on this site I started wondering about the fastest way to delete all rows with a certain condition.

The above-referenced question came with various solutions:

(1) Loop through all rows on the sheet (backward) and delete all rows one-by-one which meet the condition.

(2) Move the applicable range into an array first and then evaluate the conditions in the array and -- based on that -- delete all rows one-by-one on the underlying sheet.

A possible improvement might be to delete all rows in chunks to reduce the overhead of accessing to the worksheet. But if you go this route then you have various options to "store" the ranges before you actually delete them:

(1) Use `Intersect` to merge the ranges which should be deleted.

(2) Simply write a `String` with all the rows to be deleted.

So, which is the fastest way to do that?

Comment: Set Application.ScreenUpdating to false and you won't have the overhead of accessing the sheet.

Comment: [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744149/code-in-vba-loops-and-never-ends-how-to-fix-this) are good examples of various methods.

Comment: BTW.. the fastest way is using `Autofilter` :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout: have a look at the subs below. Based on these results it seems that you are incorrect and there is a faster approach.

Comment: I am biased towards [array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34028430/deleting-via-autofilter-takes-too-long).

Comment: There are a _lot_ of Q/A on this on SO.  And besides, if you want to know which is fastest in your specific case, do your own tests

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One efficient solution is to tag all the rows to keep and move all the rows to delete at the end by sorting the tags.
This way, the complexity doesn't increase with the number of rows to delete.

This example deletes in less than a second, for 50000 rows, all the rows where column `I` is equal to `2`:

```
Sub DeleteMatchingRows()
    Dim rgTable As Range, rgTags As Range, data(), tags(), count&, r&

    ' load the data in an array
    Set rgTable = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    data = rgTable.Value

    ' tag all the rows to keep with the row number. Leave empty otherwise.
    ReDim tags(1 To UBound(data), 1 To 1)
    tags(1, 1) = 1  ' keep the header
    For r = 2 To UBound(data)
      If data(r, 9) <> 2 Then tags(r, 1) = r  ' if column I <> 2 keep the row
    Next

    ' insert the tags in the last column on the right
    Set rgTags = rgTable.Columns(rgTable.Columns.count + 1)
    rgTags.Value = tags

    ' sort the rows on the tags which will move the rows to delete at the end
    Union(rgTable, rgTags).Sort key1:=rgTags, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
    count = rgTags.End(xlDown).Row

    ' delete the tags on the right and the rows that weren't tagged
    rgTags.EntireColumn.Delete
    rgTable.Resize(UBound(data) - count + 1).Offset(count).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Note that it doesn't alter the order of the rows.

Comment: ++ Definitely a faster way :) It is much faster than autofilter. Removing my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Here are all the possible options I could think of with an "average time" to complete the tasks:

```
Option Base 1
Option Explicit

Sub FixWithArraysAndDeleteRange()

Dim lngItem As Long
Dim varArray() As Variant
Dim wksItem As Worksheet
Dim rngRangeToDelete As Range

Dim dttStart As Date

Worksheets(1).Range("I25:I50000").Formula = "=RandBetween(1, 5)"
Worksheets(1).Range("I25:I50000").Value2 = Worksheets(1).Range("I25:I50000").Value2

dttStart = Now()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

Set wksItem = Worksheets(1)
varArray() = wksItem.Range("I25:I50000").Value2

For lngItem = LBound(varArray) To UBound(varArray)
    If IsNumeric(varArray(lngItem, 1)) Then
        If Int(varArray(lngItem, 1)) = 2 Then
            If rngRangeToDelete Is Nothing Then
              Set rngRangeToDelete = wksItem.Rows(lngItem + 24)
            Else
              Set rngRangeToDelete = Intersect(rngRangeToDelete, wksItem.Rows(lngItem + 24))
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next lngItem

rngRangeToDelete.EntireRow.Delete

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True

Debug.Print Format(Now() - dttStart, "HH:MM:SS")
'Average time around 0 seconds

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub FixWithLoop()

Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim wksItem As Worksheet

Dim dttStart As Date

Worksheets(1).Range("I25:I50000").Formula = "=RandBetween(1, 5)"
Worksheets(1).Range("I25:I50000").Value2 = Worksheets(1).Range("I25:I50000").Value2

dttStart = Now()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

Set wksItem = Worksheets(1)
lngLastRow = wksItem.Cells(wksItem.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row

For lngRow = lngLastRow To 25 Step -1
    If Int(wksItem.Cells(lngRow, "I").Value) = 2 Then wksItem.Rows(lngRow).Delete
Next lngRow

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True

Debug.Print Format(Now() - dttStart, "HH:MM:SS")
'Average time ~3 seconds

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub FixWithLoopInChunks()

Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim wksItem As Worksheet
Dim strRowsToDelete As String
Dim intDeleteCount As Integer

Dim dttStart As Date

Worksheets(1).Range("I25:I50000").Formula = "=RandBetween(1, 5)"
Worksheets(1).Range("I25:I50000").Value2 = Worksheets(1).Range("I25:I50000").Value2

dttStart = Now()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

Set wksItem = Worksheets(1)
lngLastRow = wksItem.Cells(wksItem.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row

For lngRow = lngLastRow To 25 Step -1
    If Int(wksItem.Cells(lngRow, "I").Value) = 2 Then
        intDeleteCount = intDeleteCount + 1
        strRowsToDelete = strRowsToDelete & ",I" & lngRow
    End If
    If intDeleteCount >= 30 Then
        strRowsToDelete = Mid(strRowsToDelete, 2)
        wksItem.Range(strRowsToDelete).EntireRow.Delete
        intDeleteCount = 0
        strRowsToDelete = ""
    End If
Next lngRow

If intDeleteCount > 0 Then
    strRowsToDelete = Mid(strRowsToDelete, 2)
    wksItem.Range(strRowsToDelete).EntireRow.Delete
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True

Debug.Print Format(Now() - dttStart, "HH:MM:SS")
'Average time ~3 seconds

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub FixWithArraysAndDeleteChunks()

Dim lngItem As Long
Dim varArray() As Variant
Dim wksItem As Worksheet
Dim strRowsToDelete As String
Dim intDeleteCount As Integer

Dim dttStart As Date

Worksheets(1).Range("I25:I50000").Formula = "=RandBetween(1, 5)"
Worksheets(1).Range("I25:I50000").Value2 = Worksheets(1).Range("I25:I50000").Value2

dttStart = Now()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

Set wksItem = Worksheets(1)
varArray() = wksItem.Range("I25:I50000").Value2

For lngItem = UBound(varArray) To LBound(varArray) Step -1
    If IsNumeric(varArray(lngItem, 1)) Then
        If Int(varArray(lngItem, 1)) = 2 Then
            intDeleteCount = intDeleteCount + 1
            strRowsToDelete = strRowsToDelete & ",I" & lngItem + 24
        End If
        If intDeleteCount >= 30 Then
            strRowsToDelete = Mid(strRowsToDelete, 2)
            wksItem.Range(strRowsToDelete).EntireRow.Delete
            intDeleteCount = 0
            strRowsToDelete = ""
        End If
    End If
Next lngItem

If intDeleteCount > 0 Then
    strRowsToDelete = Mid(strRowsToDelete, 2)
    wksItem.Range(strRowsToDelete).EntireRow.Delete
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True

Debug.Print Format(Now() - dttStart, "HH:MM:SS")
'Average time ~2 seconds

End Sub
```

Based on the above tests the "fastest" route is to use an array, save the range of rows to be deleted using `Intersect`and then delete all rows together.

<sub>Note, if you are using `Application.Union` instead of `Intersect` then the time of that approach drops significantly and the sub will run for almost 30 seconds.</sub>

Yet, the time difference is very small and negligible (for 50.000 rows).

Please do let me know if my speed-test-setup has any flaws which might bias the results or if I am missing another approach you would like to see.

### Update:

Here is another approach offered by @SiddharthRout. I do not wish to plagiarise. Yet, I wanted to compare time results. Hence, here is the sub rewritten to compare to the others with the average time recorded on my system.

```
Sub DeleteFilteredRows_SiddharthRout()

Dim wksItem As Worksheet
Dim rngRowsToDelete As Range

Dim dttStart As Date

Worksheets(1).Range("I25:I50000").Formula = "=RandBetween(1, 5)"
Worksheets(1).Range("I25:I50000").Value2 = Worksheets(1).Range("I25:I50000").Value2

dttStart = Now()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

Set wksItem = Worksheets(1)
wksItem.AutoFilterMode = False
wksItem.Range("I25:I50000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=2
Set rngRowsToDelete = wksItem.Range("I25:I50000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
wksItem.AutoFilterMode = False
wksItem.Rows.Hidden = False

rngRowsToDelete.EntireRow.Delete

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True

Debug.Print Format(Now() - dttStart, "HH:MM:SS")
'Average time around 5 seconds

End Sub
```

It seems that this approach is slightly slower compared to all the others.

Answer (score 2):

**edited**

after some more testings it seems that `Sort`&`Delete` is a little faster than `RemoveDuplicates`

so I put in the following solution (keeping the first one for reference by the end of the answer)

```
Sub FixWithSort()
Dim testRng As Range
Dim dttStart As Date

Set testRng = Worksheets("Test").Range("I25:I50000")

With testRng
    .Formula = "=RandBetween(1, 5)"
    .Value2 = .Value2
End With

dttStart = Now()

With testRng
    With .Offset(, 1)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]=2,"""",row())"
        .Value2 = .Value2
    End With

    .Resize(, 2).Sort key1:=.Columns(2), Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
    Range(.Cells(1, 2).End(xlDown).Offset(1, -1), .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown)).EntireRow.Delete
    .Columns(2).ClearContents
End With

Debug.Print Format(Now() - dttStart, "HH:MM:SS")
dttStartGlobal = dttStartGlobal + Now() - dttStart

End Sub
```

previous (and a little slower) solution with `RemoveDuplicates`

```
Option Explicit

Sub FixWithRemoveDuplicates()
Dim testRng As Range
Dim dttStart As Date

Set testRng = Worksheets("Test").Range("I25:I50000")

With testRng
    .Formula = "=RandBetween(1, 5)"
    .Value2 = .Value2
End With

dttStart = Now()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

With testRng
    With .Offset(, 1)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]=2,""a"",row())"
        .Value2 = .Value2
    End With
    .EntireRow.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(.Columns(2).Column), Header:=xlNo
    .Offset(, 1).Find(what:="a", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).EntireRow.Delete
    .Columns(2).ClearContents
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True

Debug.Print Format(Now() - dttStart, "HH:MM:SS")
'Average time around 0 seconds

End Sub
```